# Writing a compareTo() method for Linked List of characters

Tags: java, linked-list, compareto

I'm having trouble writing a `compareTo()` and `charAt()` methods for a linked list object that builds strings. The class, called `LString` contains a constructor and a few other methods. It runs with another file that tests its ability as a linked list string builder, and I am receiving this error message:

```
Running constructor, length, toString tests (10 tests)
Starting tests: ..........
Time: 0.000
OK! (10 tests passed.)

Running compareTo and equals tests (18 tests)
Starting tests: EEEEEEEEEEEE......
Time: 0.015

There were 12 failures:
1) t21aTestCompareTo[0](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: compareTo of "abc" and "abd" wrong expected:<-1> but was:<0>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t21aTestCompareTo(LStringTest.java:259)
        ... 9 more
2) t22aTestEquals[0](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: equals of "abc" and "abd" wrong expected:<false> but was:<true>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t22aTestEquals(LStringTest.java:269)
        ... 9 more
3) t21aTestCompareTo[1](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: compareTo of "a" and "" wrong expected:<1> but was:<0>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t21aTestCompareTo(LStringTest.java:261)
        ... 9 more
4) t22aTestEquals[1](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: equals of "" and "a" wrong expected:<false> but was:<true>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t22aTestEquals(LStringTest.java:269)
        ... 9 more
5) t21aTestCompareTo[2](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: compareTo of "a" and "ab" wrong expected:<-1> but was:<0>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t21aTestCompareTo(LStringTest.java:259)
        ... 9 more
6) t22aTestEquals[2](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: equals of "a" and "ab" wrong expected:<false> but was:<true>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t22aTestEquals(LStringTest.java:269)
        ... 9 more
7) t21aTestCompareTo[3](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: compareTo of "abc" and "abcd" wrong expected:<-1> but was:<0>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t21aTestCompareTo(LStringTest.java:259)
        ... 9 more
8) t22aTestEquals[3](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: equals of "abc" and "abcd" wrong expected:<false> but was:<true>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t22aTestEquals(LStringTest.java:269)
        ... 9 more
9) t21aTestCompareTo[4](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: compareTo of "B" and "a" wrong expected:<-1> but was:<0>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)

        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t21aTestCompareTo(LStringTest.java:259)
        ... 9 more
10) t22aTestEquals[4](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: equals of "B" and "a" wrong expected:<false> but was:<true>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t22aTestEquals(LStringTest.java:269)
        ... 9 more
11) t21aTestCompareTo[5](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: compareTo of "BB" and "Ba" wrong expected:<-1> but was:<0>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t21aTestCompareTo(LStringTest.java:259)
        ... 9 more
12) t22aTestEquals[5](LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: equals of "BB" and "Ba" wrong expected:<false> but was:<true>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at LStringTest$LStringCompareToTest.t22aTestEquals(LStringTest.java:269)
        ... 9 more

Test Failed! (12 of 18 tests failed.)

Test failures: abandoning other phases.
```

The `LString` class is meant to mimic Java's `String` and `StringBuilder`, but with Linked Lists instead of arrays. I'm a little confused on how to use the `this` keyword. Within the `compareTo()` method below, I imagine using `this` by saying to myself "if this LStrings character at this index is equal to the argument's LString character at the same index, return 0."

I'm referencing this page, but unsure how to write it efficiently: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

I want `compareTo()` to return 0 if the LStrings have the exact same characters, a value less than zero if this LString is lexicographically less than anotherLString, and a value greater than zero if its lexicographically greater.

```
public class LString    {

     node   front;
     int size;

     private class node {
          char data;
          node next;

          public node (){
          }

          public node (char newData){
                this.data = newData;
          }

          public node (char newData, node newNext){
                this.data = newData;
                this.next = newNext;
          }


     }

     public LString(){
          this.size = 0;
          this.front =  null;
     }
     public LString(String original) {
        this.size = original.length();
        if (original != ""){

          this.front =  new node(original.charAt(0));
          node curr = this.front;

          for   (int i =1; i <  original.length(); i++) {
                curr.next = new node(original.charAt(i));
                curr = curr.next;
           }
        }



     }


     public int length()    {
        return this.size;
    }
    public int compareTo(LString anotherLString)    {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.length(); i++) {
         if (this.charAt(i) == anotherLString.charAt(i)) {
            return 0;
         }
         //other logic for returning 1 or -1
      }
      return this.length()-anotherLString.length();
    }
    public boolean  equals(Object other) {
        if  (other == null  ||  !(other instanceof LString)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            LString otherLString = (LString)other;
            return true;
        }
    }
    public char charAt(int index)   {
        //return this.charAt(index)?
    }
}
```

The methods in question are unfinished in this code. Any advice is appreciated, trying to learn Java.

Comment: Should you be comparing the `data`? Also `data` is one single `char`? Why not use a `String` or `char[]`?

Comment: I'm comparing their lexicographic values.

Comment: Answer is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824474/lstring-class-using-linked-lists-to-make-strings-java/28826014#28826014

Answer (score 0):

```
   public int compareTo(LString anotherLString)    {
         for (int i = 0; i < this.length() && i<anotherLString.length(); i++) {
            if (this.charAt(i) == anotherLString.charAt(i)) {
               return 0;
            }
            else if(((int)this.charAt(i))<((int)anotherLString.charAt(i)))
               return -1;
            else
               return 1;
         }
         return this.length()-anotherLString.length();
       }
```

I think this solution should work fine for your requirement. I have type casted `char` to `int` and then compared them to return -1 / 1. Additionally I also added length restriction on your for loop.

**Note:** Using `charAt(index)` is **not** efficient solution here, since you iterate through your linked list each time you fetch character. Instead you should iterate through your linked list directly for your comparison.